# PHP set time limit wait to run the script

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to wait for 20 secs before it run the script?

I mean I try set_time_limit(20) but when I click the button, it always run the script.

I guess the time limit was just for the time limit when the script running then it will stop.

im looking for a function that can help me for my script to wait for 20 secs. I know it will work on jQuery but im holding right was Yii framework.

I have sample script below

```
$coco = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM gameWaiting" );
if ( empty( $coco ) ) {
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO gameWaiting VALUE('', '$email', '$language')" );
$status = 0; // IF THE STATUS is equal to 0 means the db was empty so it will insert
// AND WAIT FOR OTHER PLAYER TO INSERT ALSO
} else {
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO gameWaiting VALUE('', '$email', '$language')" );
$status = 1; // IF THE STATUS is equal to 1 means the db was !empty so it will insert also
// BUT THERE is no need to wait for other player otherwise RAND() the user.
}

// NOW SET TIME HERE when it will INSERT to the game
if ( time was equal to set) {
// IF SOMEONE insert into gameWaiting it will create game
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO game VALUE('','name','email','language')" );
} else {
// No player was added
}

echo $status;
```

I hope this is possible...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php ? Cannot think why anyone would wont to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set_time_limit()` specifies the maximum execution time for the script, not the time to wait until executing it (see the [**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)).

You can use PHP's [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function to force execution to delay by a given number of seconds:

```
sleep(20);
```

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to accept the answer to help your rating.

Answer (score 3):

You can pause the script using `sleep()` function.

```
sleep(20)
```

make sure `set_time_limit` is higher than this

Answer (score 1):

try this php

```
sleep(10);
```

replace 10 as you want